# TypeScript+Angular: Property is missing in type [2322]

Tags: angular, aplicação-web, typescript

Eu estou tendo um problema num Mock de usuário que eu estou fazendo no TS, é meu primeiro site na vida e eu to meio perdido com alguns erros. Acabo perdendo horas tentando resolver erros simples

[image: Meu erro]

Esse é o erro, só que eu não sei o que ta errado porque parece igual ao do constructor da classe usuario.model que segue abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De onde surgiu essa Property 'Nome' que que eu não estou enxergando? Desculpa se errei em alguma coisa, é minha segunda postagem aqui só.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript é o Javascript só que tipado, quando você criar um array do tipo usuário, você precisa preencher com objetos do tipo usuário.

Segue trecho do código abaixo:

```
export class Usuario{
    private _nome: string;

    constructor(nome: string){
       _nome = nome;
    }
}

const USUARIO: Array<Usuario> = [
    new Usuario("teste"),
    new Usuario("teste2")
];
```